# How to get all the streams serialized in a file

Tags: c#, deserialization, binaryformatter

Lets say my file have 2 class that are serialized using BinaryFormatter. I need to use `(ClassName1)formatter.Deserialize(file)`

`(ClassName2)formatter.Deserialize(file)`

to get the specific stream and access its data. Is there any method to display all the class names that are present in the file? Like `ClassName1, ClassName2`

Comment: You will need to save this data. In Any case, if you store all the serialized classed in the same file, you need to know where each class bytes starts and ends. One way is to have a separate index file that holds this data.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, if you are looking for performance you should save class names in a seperate file. 
If not, you can always use :

```
string className = formatter.Deserialize(file).GetType().Name
```

which will return the class names `ClassName1` or `ClassName2`